# Duplicate resources error with the duplicate-finder plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a project consisting of a lot of sub projects. Consider three modules A,B,C. B depends on A and C depends on A and B. Both A,B,C have a test-applicationContext.xml files each. C uses A and B as a test-jar dependency. The problem is the duplicate finder plugin throws duplicate resources error for test-applicationContext.xml while compiling C. I tried to remove the test resources from module B by using the `<excludes>` tag on the test-jar goal but maven still copies over the test resources from the test-classes directory. I verified that the test-jar created for module B does not have the xml file. Could anybody tell what is wrong?

A is packaged as a test jar only, whereas B has both a main jar as well as a test-jar goal. Pom file for C is as follows:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>my.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>A</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>B</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

A has test-applicationContext.xml as follows:

```
A ---> src/main/resources/test-applicationContext.xml
```

whereas B has the xml as follows

```
B ---> src/test/resources/test-applicationContext.xml
```

I get the following error while doing mvn install on C

```
[WARNING] Found duplicate and different resources in [my.project:B:jar:tests, my.project:A]:
[WARNING]   test-applicationContext.xml
[WARNING] Found duplicate classes/resources in test classpath.
```

I cannot rename either of those files as they are references in spring config classes that I have written. I have added this as well to B:

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>test-jar</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
             <excludes>
               <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
             </excludes>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
       </executions>
</plugin>
```

I dont want to remove the test resources from A because they are like reference resources which run by default if the module that depends on it does not have its own.

Help please!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Would tweaking `maven-duplicate-finder-plugin`'s `checkTestClasspath` work for you? I had a similar issue, and it went away when I added it:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.ning.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-duplicate-finder-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <failBuildInCaseOfConflict>true</failBuildInCaseOfConflict>
        <checkTestClasspath>false</checkTestClasspath>
        <ignoredResources>
            ...
        </ignoredResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Major caveat:** Assuming I understand what's going on correctly here, you'll need to be careful that you're not breaking the stability of your tests. That is, if *all* of the following are true:

- project C has a resource `Foo.props`, *and*
- project A has the same resource `Foo.props` in its `test-jar`, *and*
- project C has a `<type>test-jar</type>` / `<scope>test</scope>` dependency on A, *and*
- project C has a test that relies on its own values in `Foo.props`

...then it's unpredictable which `Foo.props` will be used by project C's tests.

If that's not a concern for you, or if I'm just wrong on this point, then I think this change may solve your problem.